# Are there any difference using pipes?

Tags: sed, perl

Using Ubuntu 12.04.

Using pipes (5 times):

```
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g' | sed 's/Y/B/g' | sed 's/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g' | sed 's/Y/B/g' | sed 's/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g' | sed 's/Y/B/g' | sed 's/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.004s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g' | sed 's/Y/B/g' | sed 's/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g' | sed 's/Y/B/g' | sed 's/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
```

not using pipes (5 times):

```
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g; s/Y/B/g; s/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.004s
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g; s/Y/B/g; s/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g; s/Y/B/g; s/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g; s/Y/B/g; s/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.000s
$ time echo XYZ | sed 's/X/A/g; s/Y/B/g; s/Z/C/g'
ABC

real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
$
```

It's clear that NOT using pipes is faster. So it can be used to optimize a script:

```
$ echo ABC | sed 's/A/X/g; s/X/Y/g'
YBC
$
```

**My question:** Merging the sed's always produce the same output?

Comment: I don't understand. Yes, the same sed commands will produce the same output. Why not?

Comment: Your benchmarks are completely worthless: the uncertainty of the measures is about 10ms, and the times are less than the uncertainty. You need to invoke this code in a loop, say, 1000 times to get anything remotely useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the two commands you posted are 100% equivalent, so you can safely change your script not to use pipes.

But your reasoning is flawed: you only measured the time it takes to `echo XYZ`, not the actual `sed` invocations. You will however see that it's still faster not to use pipes :)

```
dennis@spirit:~$ time sh -c 'echo XYZ | sed -e s/X/A/ | sed -e s/Y/B/ | sed -e s/Z/C/'
ABC

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.012s
dennis@spirit:~$ time sh -c 'echo XYZ | sed -e s/X/A/ -e s/Y/B/ -e s/Z/C/'
ABC

real    0m0.006s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.006s
```

Comment: Why do you say _you only measured the time it takes to `echo XYZ`_? did you even try it? compare (in Bash) `time echo XYZ | true` and `time echo XYZ | for i in {1..1000000}; do :; done`. From `help time`: _Report time consumed by pipeline's execution._

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that when you are use *pipes* to perform different substitutions then the shell needs to fork multiple times.

On the other hand, a `sed` expression containing commands for various substitutions requires the shell to fork just once.

As such, it'd be more efficient to have various commands in a single expression like:

```
sed 's/X/A/g; s/Y/B/g; s/Z/C/g'
```

To answer the second part, the above is equivalent to the following *slower* variant:

```
sed 's/X/A/g' | sed 's/Y/B/g' | sed 's/Z/C/g'
```

Comment: You don't just fork the shell multiple times, you also invoke a new instance of `sed` each time...

Comment: @Shadur I guess I should've been explicit about it.  If the shell is `exec`ing a process, then the process would be `exec`ed.  Maybe it's not so obvious.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a GNU extension to `sed` that  conditionally forks for you:

```
sed '/num/s//echo "$((num+1))"/e'

info sed
```

> `e`
>
> > This command allows one to pipe input from a shell command into pattern space.  If a substitution was made, the command that is found in pattern space is executed and pattern space is replaced with its output.  A trailing newline is suppressed; results are undefined if the command to be executed contains a NUL character.
>
> This is a GNU `sed' extension.